# Angular setting a default number value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want a input field with a type `number` to have a default value `1` when the page opens. I set the `value="1"` but, it didn't change anything and the input field is still empty. What should I add to fix it?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="WorkItemSelection.CopyQuantity"
         name="CopyQuantity" value="1">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Set your model's `CopyQuantity` to 1 I expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `value="1"`. Just in your `.ts` do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  WorkItemSelection.CopyQuantity = 1;
}
```

Comment: angular uses two-way binding which means that you can set a value by default and it will change the DOM. @hectic-platypus